# removing a malware on my website

Tags: malware

After a longer period of time, I went to visit one of my sites, tasmamiandevilz and a security alert popped up. Never happened to me before, so I did some Googling.. and apparently the `sso.anbtr.com` is quite common. 
The issue is, that all the information I was able to find was on how to remove it *from my PC*.

The issue is, I am pretty sure it's not a problem of my PC, but rather the website itself. This is the only website where I get the error and I don't seem to have any other symptoms. [image: sso.anbtr.com]

Is it possible that the malware would be directly on my site ? How can I get rid of it ?

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry but there is already a vast amount of questions regarding malware and virus's on Pro Webmasters. Other revelant questions are http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/81676/firefox-accusing-me-of-distributing-malware-on-my-site and http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/28868/clean-an-attacked-website/28872#28872 if using WordPress

Answer (score 2):

#### I am pretty sure it's not a problem of my PC, but rather the website itself

This is a strange report, as it appears your website in **not** infected according to Google Safe Browsing (and other online tests for infected websites).

Please read [How can I remove malicious spyware, malware, adware, viruses, trojans or rootkits from my PC?](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-adware-viruses-trojans-or-rootkit).

[Google Safe Browsing](https://www.google.com/transparencyreport/safebrowsing/diagnostic/#url=tasmamiandevilz.com) is showing no malware for tasmamiandevilz.com:

[image]

In addition there is no malware detected by [virustotal.com](https://www.virustotal.com/en/url/6b4a83f2cb3bae51e36a38d0fb3864a9e86c1955a7ab4b672c4aa3817bb3aa12/analysis/1446195120/) or [scanurl.net](http://scanurl.net/?u=tasmamiandevilz.com&uesb=Check%20This%20URL&PageSpeed=noscript):

[image]

[image]

Comment: yes, the weird thing is however, that it only happens with that one site and only with Chrome. In firefox, it runs all good. I also don't have any other signs of malware on my PC.