# My website is Google shielding, help me thankyou

Tags: google-search-console, openx

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Users often say my website is infected, but can't find any evidence of this?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/25189/users-often-say-my-website-is-infected-but-cant-find-any-evidence-of-this)

This is my website is google shielding。In firefox to show in the web site has the virus, but in other browsers without this kind of situation。

Comment: my website http://www.thebeijinger.com/

Answer (score 2):

Firefox shows the following information about the infections you're experiencing

[image]

However [Virus Total](https://www.virustotal.com/url/5328bf516a29b418a919d3d1d6907098339619e78cddac14ffe78824052f2d87/analysis/) reports that your website is clean (I checked five pages), [MYWot](http://www.mywot.com/) shows no problems, [IPVoid](http://www.ipvoid.com/scan/211.147.216.228/) shows your IP doesn't appear on any blacklists, and [MXToolbox](http://www.mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=blacklist:211.147.216.228) shows that you don't appear on any spam blacklists.

My guess is that this was caused by a third party advert so you should check your suppliers carefully, if the advert no longer appears on your site and you're certain that any malware is gone then you need to [Request a Malware Review](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=168328) from Google.

I would also advise opening a webmaster tools account, if you don't already have one, as GWT can help you [detect and purge malware](https://sites.google.com/site/webmasterhelpforum/en/faq-malware-and-hacked-sites) from your site.

If it detects an infection Google will send an email to all of the following addresses `abuse@, admin@, administrator@, contact@, info@, postmaster@, support@, webmaster@` so you should ensure that you have at least one of these in place and monitored.